# What is wrong with this substitution?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = "sad day
 Good day
 May be Bad Day 
 ";

$s =~ s/\w+ \w+/_/gm;

print $s;
```

I am trying to substitute all spaces between words with _, but it is not working.  What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern replacement is probably the most efficient solution:

```
$a =~ s/\b \b/_/g;
```

Comment: Please don't use `$a` or `$b` in examples unless it involves [sorting](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: @Zaid - Good point, but I was just using the same variables as the OP.

Answer (score 5):

The substitution replaces an entire word (`\w+`) then a space then an other word by an underscore.

There is really no need to replace (or capture for what matters) those words

```
$a=~s/\b +\b/_/gm;
```

will replace a word break ( `\b`, a zero-width transition between a word and a non word) followed by one or more spaces followed by an other word break, by an underscore. Using `\b` ensures that you don't replace a space after or before a new line.

Comment: Please don't use `$a` or `$b` in examples unless it involves [sorting](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: `$a` was used in the question (and in your answer!). For the spectators here, `$a` and `$b` are "predeclared" in Perl, so you can use it in sort routines under `strict`. I have never been sure why that made it bad to use them anywhere else though.

Comment: I see where you got the `$a` from, looks like Chas took care of it. And I could've sworn I used `$s`! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This question wouldn't be complete without an answer involving explicit [look-ahead and look-behind assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind):

```
$s =~ s/(?<=\w) (?=\w+)/_/g
```

- This is effectively the same as the solutions involving the zero-width word-boundary anchor, `\b`.
- Note that look-ahead regexes can match regexes of any character length, but look-behind regexes have to be of fixed-length (which is why `(?<=\w+)` can't be done).

Comment: +1. I've never really used the look-ahead and look-behind assertions that much. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you don't need the `+` in the lookahead either. To make up for it, you missed the `+` after the space character ;)